# Can't find rule grammarSpec or tree structure error while using direct left recursion

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr4

I am trying to parse a Prolog term and the rule is as follows:

```
term[ReadOptions Options, int priority]
:
simpleTerm[$Options]
|
term[$Options, $priority - 1]
;
```

But running ANTLR throws the following errors:

```
can't find rule grammarSpec or tree structure error:
...My complete code here...
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)          
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.visit(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:206)
org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.visitGrammar(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:200)
org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolCollector.process(SymbolCollector.java:76)
org.antlr.v4.semantics.SemanticPipeline.process(SemanticPipeline.java:103)
org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:399)
...
org.antlr.v4.tool.LeftRecursiveRule.getAltLabels(LeftRecursiveRule.java:91)
org.antlr.v4.tool.Rule.hasAltSpecificContexts(Rule.java:200)
org.antlr.v4.tool.LeftRecursiveRule.hasAltSpecificContexts(LeftRecursiveRule.java:60)
org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolChecks.checkForLabelConflicts(SymbolChecks.java:150)
org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolChecks.process(SymbolChecks.java:98)
org.antlr.v4.semantics.SemanticPipeline.process(SemanticPipeline.java:107)
org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:399)
org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:384)
org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:343)
org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:190)
```

Removing the last line of my rule removes all errors. If I write

```
term[ReadOptions Options, int priority]
:
simpleTerm[$Options]
;
```

Isn't ANTLR4 supposed to be able to handle such grammars as only direct left recursion is involved ?

Comment: Could you remove all the custom code from you grammar? The main reason I'm not keen on looking at your question is because the ANTLR grammars you post here on SO (not just this question) mainly consist of custom code (locals-block, rule-return statements, inline code, etc.) that have nothing to do with the question, and should therefore be omitted from it (IMO).

Comment: Yes I have done that. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, and thanks for cleaning it up. I can't test it right now, so I won't post this as an answer: could you try placing the left recursive `term` *not* as the last alternative: instead of `term : simpleTerm | term;`, try `term : term | simpleTerm;`

Comment: I just tried that but the same error is still there. Could it be because I am passing parameters to the rules ? Because that's about the only odd thing I can notice.

Comment: Should I list this as an ANTLR4 bug ?

Comment: This could have something to do with the following:
    trial : trial | COMMA;

This will throw the same error as the one I have discussed in the question. But the example I gave should not throw an error as there parameters are getting changed.

Comment: No idea (not enough info in your question to determine that). If you think it is, feel free to [open an issue on Github](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues?milestone=4&sort=updated&state=open). Be sure to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that others can easily reproduce the issue.